# Merging specific columns from multiple excel files in R?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, merge

apologies for what is probably an already-answered question, I couldn't seem to find what I was looking for in the archives.

I'm currently in the process of trying to merge multiple excel files into one df for data analysis.

It's experimental data across different versions, and the variables in each column in excel are inconsistent (ie, in Version 1, ReactionTime is in Column AB, in Version 2 it's in AG). I need to merge the values from specified variables from the (~24) data files with different column structures into one long format df.

I've only ever used an excel macro to merge files before, and am unsure of how to go about specifying the variable names for merging. Any help you could provide would be appreciated!

Comment: See related post on how to read multiple files into R, in your case we would want to use `readxl::read_excel()` and subset. (There are many other packages that can import excel files into R).

Comment: Something like this: `myfiles <- lapply(list.files(pattern="*.xlsx"), function(i){ d <- read_excel(i); d[, "ReactionTime"]})`

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11433432/680068